# Sublime is killed when logging out from ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, sublime-text

When I'm logging out from xubuntu 14.04 sublime text 3 is killed. Don't know why. I thinks some process is killed, which is parent to sublime. Other text editors is'nt killed (Mousepad for example). Also mongo shell is killed and virtualenv deactivated. How can I configure logging out not to kill anything?

Comment: I guess this is how things work. Unless they are services. when you logout all of your programs will be killed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how things work. Unless they are services. when you logout, all of your programs will be killed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I solved this terrible problem - in fact i just wanted to lock my screen, simply type xflock4 in terminal

Answer (score 0):

With easy words:

Sublime doesn't catch the kill signal or acts in the right way. During logout, your systems sends a kill signal to running processes to give them the possibility to close itself in a proper way. After some time still running processes will be killed in the hard way, means the processes will be destroyed.

Now make your decision. Logout and the processes will be killed or lock your screen.